# Getting wrong value while using property mediator in WSO2 ESB

Tags: properties, wso2, mediator

I am using a property "INC" to store a incoming message(which is showing properly in logs) and doing mapping properly by payload mediator.

The modified structure that I am getting by payload is as below.(which is getting properly mapped)

Later, I am using callout mediator as below to get response from this endpoint.

using LogText to see the response.

Then adding filter as below:

`<property name="INC" expression="get-property('IntRequest')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>`

`<property name="LogText" value="call response" scope="default" type="STRING"/>`

`<filter xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:platformFaults="urn:faults_2015_1.platform.webservices.com" source="//platformFaults:code/text()" regex="WS_CONCUR_SESSION_DISALLWD">
  <then>
    <log level="full" separator=",*Fault in Call***">
      <property name="REQUEST" expression="get-property('INC')" scope="default" type="STRING" />
    </log>
  </then>
  <else/>
</filter>`

But, here I am not getting value of REQUEST.. it is showing the value of "call response"..
How will I get the value of REQUEST properly??

Comment: You question is not clear. Do you have a property named `IntRequest`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the enrich mediator to store the request message body

```
<enrich>
  <source clone="true" type="body"/>
  <target property="Request_Message" type="property"/>
</enrich>
```

then call the property

```
<log>
    <property expression="get-property('Request_Message')" name="REQUEST"/>
</log>
```

Answer (score 0):

where did you define "IntRequest" property in your sequence? I couldn't find it in your configuration. If you change the log level to custom it would be more clear to see the value of request in the system log